# Best practices to update multiple maria database instances from application

Tags: database, mariadb, database-replication

we have two databases in different servers for maria DB, Primary and secondary.As Master-Slave relation is not in place. We need to update both the data bases for each user actions.
Example: If add employee action performed from front end by user. We need to insert employee details in Primary data base first and later in secondary.

We designed to insert separately to database ie two insert call's from application for each Database.

As we have multiple DB interaction for single operation, this solution will effect performance.

Is there any way we can achieve this by using procedure or UDF's?

Any better approaches or suggestion are helpfull

Comment: Regardless of the implementation (other than Replication), you need 2 connections and 2 `INSERTs`.  So, plan on a user action taking twice as long.  But if that is (2 * 30ms), it is not "bad".

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways we can do what you are looking for. Of course, there are pros and cons of each approach.

1. The simplest one would be to use MaxScale's "Tee" filter, that can automatically execute all your queries on multiple servers. This is, of course, transparent to the application code.

**Refer to:** https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-tee-filter/

The benefit is that it does with the least amount of strain on your application performance as it doesn't have to make two calls to execute your statements on the databases and your application code remains simple.

Negative of this is that, there are no return values form the "tee" filter! You won't be able to tell if the insert, update, delete was successful or not.

2. The other method that might be much better is to use the "Spider" storage engine in MariaDB and connect to the remote table on the remote MariaDB server.

Now you can create a trigger on your primary table and depending on your business logic/requirements, you can update the Spider table, a.k.a Remote table, from within the trigger. This will give you more control and your application is still kept clean without dual connections.

Another benefit of this is that if due to some reason your Trigger fails to update the remote "Spider" table, your primary transaction will also fail! This will ensure proper data integrity is maintained :)

There are other engines that can be used similarly like "CONNECT" but "Spider" is the only officially supported among the ones that can connect to a remote database's table. Spider, however, can only connect as long as the remote database is also MariaDB.

Hope this answers your question and is what you are looking for :)

Cheers,
Faisal.